# Are salaries for academic jobs in New Zealand negotiable?

Tags: professorship, salary, negotiation, new-zealand

The academic salaries and compensations in new zealand universities seem tobe fairly low compared to most other countries such as US, UK, Australia, etc. Is it however possible to negotiate the starting point in the prescribed academic levels (read: salary levels)? Are the salary levels also related to the No of years post phd?

Comment: Everything is negotiable if both parties are sufficiently invested.

Comment: Please don't make edits that dramatically change your question. "What exactly determines the level of appointment in NZ universities?" is not the same question as "Are salaries negotiable," so please ask it separately.

Answer (score 4):

Your starting salary is indeed negotiable for New Zealand positions. Whether you get what you ask for will usually be tied to your relevant experience. This last point is related to your further question about experience post-phD. For research positions, your research output during your years post-PhD will be a strong driver for what your starting salary will be.