# What is relationship between post-doc experience and number of publications on Salary/appointment levels in New Zealand universities?

Tags: professorship, salary, new-zealand

This question is related to [What is the average salary of assistant professor in New Zealand?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34493/what-is-the-average-salary-of-assistant-professor-in-new-zealand?lq=1)
and
[Are salaries for academic jobs in New Zealand negotiable?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40408/are-salaries-for-academic-jobs-in-new-zealand-negotiable?lq=1)

Is the relation between number of years of postdoc experience and/or publications with the appointment/salary level at NZ universities quantifiable? I am mainly interested in the starting level appointment.

Answer (score 3):

New Zealand is heavily invested in the "Publish or Perish" mindset, to the point where it's not even funny. Research funding is allocated entirely on the basis of an exercise called the PBRF (http://www.tec.govt.nz/Funding/Fund-finder/Performance-Based-Research-Fund-PBRF-/) and academics spend a significant amount of their time preparing for this. More publications are better; the venues are not so important (although New Zealand academics do not typically publish in predatory journals.) The quantity of publications is probably the single most important factor in any hiring decision by a New Zealand university.

[PS. Looking at your questions, many of them seem to be about "New Zealand Universities" in general. Bear in mind that there are only eight universities in New Zealand, several of which might not have a program in your area. It might be a good idea to address your questions to people who are in New Zealand, rather than random StackExchangers who may be tempted to Google the answer to earn internet points. For example, you could look for an Australia/New Zealand mailing list for academics in your subject and try asking the same questions there.]

Comment: I've seen a few New Zealanders on here (myself included), though I think most have moved overseas and I'm not aware of any professors in NZ on here. Questions about NZ are not bad questions, but I agree that unfortunately I doubt we have the expertise here to answer them any better than Google can.

Comment: I have a real opportunity to go to a ANZ university (shortlisted at three places with interviews lined up immediately) so questions on ANZ system. If it has only 8 universities, so does Ireland or other countries of similar population size. I am not from either of these countries. I am surprised by your comnts in brkts. StackExchange is the best way to get an answer to such questions compared to a more formal academic forum where people might be hesitant to express their negative views if any. I trust the StackExchangers that they are here to give honest answers rather than earning points.

Comment: That not enough information available about the ANZ system to outsiders is exactly why I have to use StackExchange.
Publish or Perish may be bad up to certain extent for sure. That's a different topic. But if you are publishing well on an average, may it not be better to go to a system which awards you (I never go for low-quality journals either)?

Comment: I don't think this is an accurate description of PBRF; you *can't* list more than sixteen publications (over six years), so more don't help, and four of them are to be singled out as the highest quality (you get to make the case in prose, so that's not necessarily by venue, but probably).

Comment: @Moriarty A few of us (myself included) have some New Zealand research and teaching experience. I drift over every once in a while. It is good that someone is asking NZ questions at least, even if they may wait some time for answers.